# Moving python modules across computers

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, python

I'm going to be getting a new laptop running 64-bit Windows 7. On my current 32-bit Windows XP laptop, I have a large number of python modules in the site-packages folder that I want on the new machine. Rather than tracking down all the installation packages and having to build and install them, would it be possible to simply copy the files from the XP machine to the Win7 machine. I'm planning on installing the same version of python that I use on XP.

Comment: It depends. I remember some versions of [numpy](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) are differently built for 32 and 64 bit.

Comment: Similar question at SO: http://stackoverflow.com/q/916952/2651145 . Also this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8636386/2651145